# Android custom preference not triggering OnPreferenceClickListener

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, onclicklistener, android-preferences

I created a custom Preference to set a background 9 patch drawable to it. I am using a OnPreferenceClickListener to open a popup when I click on the preference. After changing from Preference to CustomPreference, the click listener stops working.

Code:

```
public class CustomPreference extends Preference {

    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(convertView, parent);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_settings_patch);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Click Listener:

```
CustomPreference preference = (CustomPreference) findPreference("custom_preference");
preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

XML:

```
<com.example.CustomPreference
            android:key="custom_preference"
            android:summary="Summary"
            android:title="Title" />
```

Comment: How do you know the click listener stops working? All it does it return. Also note that returning `true` in `onPreferenceClick` signifies that the click event was handled and the default click action should not take place.

Comment: There is some code inside, I just removed it from the question bcus I don't want it to get posted